# How to cancel Net Core 6.0 web API request when Client aborted?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to cancel a long-running action on the server side when the client cancels or aborts the request. I am using ASP.Net Core 6.0 and the fetch API with Signal.
`HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested` is always false.

```cs
while (true)
{
   CancellationToken cancellationToken = HttpContext.RequestAborted;

   if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      tokenSource2.Cancel();
   }
}
```

Comment: can [this blog](https://code-maze.com/canceling-http-requests-in-asp-net-core-with-cancellationtoken/) help you? it also related to cancel token

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `CancellationToken` to your action and pass it down to your long-running task:

```cs
[HttpGet("slow")]
public async Task<string> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Your slow action
    var result = await CalculateResultAsync(10000, cancellationToken);

    return result;
}
```

And in your long-running task:

```cs
public async Task<string> CalculateResultAsync(int input, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < input; i++)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    return "Finished!";
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me, How can I call using `fetch(url, options)` from the client side?

Comment: @NishilAthikkal You don't need to do anything special in the client side, when you close the tab for example the browser will send a cancelled message to the server which in turn will trigger `CancellationToken` in your C# code

Comment: I am getting ```IsCancellationRequested``` always as false. But on the client-side request is already cancelled, I can see it Network tab. I tried ```HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested``` but got false after the client cancels the request. (using fetch() to call the API)

Comment: @NishilAthikkal I've edited my answer and added how you would use the `CancellationToken`

Comment: I used this, but in my scenario, even though the client terminated the request, the server-side 'IsCancellationRequested' is false. hence it is not throwing the exception.

Comment: FYI, server-side: Net core 6.0 and local debug running on Kestrel, is there any problem with setting 'IsCancellationRequested' in Kestrel?

Comment: @NishilAthikkal I double-checked, and it works, can you post the rest of your code. The issue is probably something else